# What are benefits of having a pre-measure to be a measure is that it is not necessarily defined on a sigma-algebra (or a sigma-ring)?

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading about [pre-measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure).
They says

> what is missing for a pre-measure to be a measure is that it is not necessarily defined on a sigma-algebra (or a sigma-ring).

I have 2 questions:

1. Examples of rings that are not sigma-rings?
2. What are concrete *benefits* of having a pre-measure to be a measure is that it is *not necessarily* defined on a sigma-algebra (or a sigma-ring), instead of a pre-measure defined **necessarily** on a sigma-algebra/ring ?

Comment: The main motivation I saw for this in my measure theory courses was to be able to build a measure with as little prespecification of its values as possible. For example, one common situation is to want to define a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with $m((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$ for $a<b$, where $F$ is an increasing right-continuous function. The fact that you can just do that freely is not so obvious since the half-open intervals are only a semiring.

Comment: The feeling it gives me is, however, that the ultimate goal is to still obtain a sigma-algebra, but using a non-sigma way to construct the same concept of measure which however brings us back to a sigma-algebra. Using pre-measures to "not limit ourselves to the sigma-algebra ", but.. in truth I see the our purpose is always measures and therefore sigma-algebra, this sounds strange to me.

Comment: I do not know, for example, I would have introduced the concept of pre-measure just to never get a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))  (countably additive function), and therefore not having to 'fall' into a sigma-algebra. Here, however, the purpose is exactly the opposite to what I expected